# the running time of the code to return hash value

Tags: java, performance, hash, time

I want to know why the running time of my code is fluctuating.

The (below) code is to output the hash value of a file. (8MB)
Firstly, the code takes a little time to return the result.
But now it takes a long time to return and sometimes it takes a little time like first time.

I don't know the real running time of the code is fast or slow.
I found out that it takes long time in `hashSum.update(buffer, 0, unitsize);`
I cannot find the reason.

The code is as follows

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Test {

    public static byte[] extractFileHashSHA256(String filename) throws Exception {

        byte[] partialHash = null;
        int buff = 16384;
        try {
            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");

            MessageDigest hashSum = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[buff];

            long read = 0;

            // calculate the hash of the hole file for the test
            long offset = file.length();
            int unitsize;
            while (read < offset) {
                unitsize = (int) (((offset - read) >= buff) ? buff : (offset - read));
                file.read(buffer, 0, unitsize);

                hashSum.update(buffer, 0, unitsize);

                read += unitsize;
            }

            file.close();
            partialHash = new byte[hashSum.getDigestLength()];
            partialHash = hashSum.digest();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return partialHash;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        String output =  new java.math.BigInteger(extractFileHashSHA256("a.pdf")).toString(16);
        System.out.println(output);

        return ;
    }   
}
```

I hope your helpful comment.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First problem: you're ignoring the return value of `read`, and assuming it always reads the whole buffer. Don't do that - `read()` returns how many bytes were *actually* read.

Comment: You can attempt to read `byte.length` every time and use the length returned which is what was actually read.

Comment: SHA-256 is meant to be expensive, how long should it take.  BTW You don't need to create a `new byte[]` for the `partialHash` you immediately discard.